# Issues with forwarding a subdomain to another port with Apache proxy

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, apache2

I have a server running Apache with a HTTPS site running on `www.example.com` and `example.com`. I'm trying to add a new site that will forward `newsite.example.com` to another port on the same server (a Docker container is listening to this other port).

My Apache sites are configured as follow,

www.example.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName www.example.com
       ServerAlias example.com
       ServerAdmin support@example.com
       DocumentRoot /home/webadmin/www.example.com/

       <Directory /home/webadmin/www.example.com/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
                Allowoverride All
       </Directory>

       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.key
       SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.ca.crt
       Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
</VirtualHost>
```

newsite.example.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName newsite.example.com
        ServerAlias newsite.example.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass / https://localhost:3000
        ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:3000
        <Proxy *>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

The SSL certificate for newsite.example.com is handled by the docker application.

After `sudo a2ensite newsite.example.com.conf && sudo service apache2 reload` trying to access either of the sites will fail with `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

**Any idea why ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the `SSLEngine On` directive in the "newsite" virtualhost definition, so it answers only to plain HTML on port 443. You need to specify the SSL directives for every virtual host which is supposed to speak SSL.

You might want to specify the following directives for newsite:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off
```

The former is necessary for SSL proxying, the latter is necessary only if the certificate is not issued for `localhost`.

Also, you might want to remove the `<Proxy>` section, as that is needed for forward proxies only.

Comment: I added the 3 directives and deleted the <Proxy> section. Apache now crashes when I enable newsite :|

Comment: I edited my question to add that the SSL certificate for newsite is handled by the dockerized application (not Apache). Does it matter ?

Comment: Ok, I was missing certs files path after the SSLEngine On. Apache and the Docker application use the same certificates. I'm not sure of what is going on here though. Is it an acceptable setup ?

Comment: You need to specify all SSL directives for every VirtualHost in order for SSL to work, so for every VirtualHost, you need at least the `SSLEngine On`, and the `SSLCertificateFile /the/full/chain.pem` directives (you might want to check the [mod_ssl documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html)). Whether it is acceptable for Docker and Apache to use the same certificate, is up to you, or any policy around there. Personally I don't see anything wrong with it.